# Non-index notation for three-dimensional tensor

Tags: notation, tensors

I would like to know what could be good notations for a three-dimensional tensor besides index notation. For instance, for the case for a one dimensional and two-dimensional tensors (vector and matrix), the arrow notations,

$$\vec{v}\text{ ,}\quad \overleftrightarrow{M}\text{ ,}$$

are commonly used, as well as the bracket ones,
$$\{v\}\text{ ,}\quad [M]\text{ .}$$

Could an analogous notation be used for a three-dimensional tensor?

Comment: I think a capital letter is fine.

Comment: Nothing's standard enough you won't need to explain it in a text you write.